# Using ngModelCtrl and inputs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been trying to wrap my head around how to use ngModelCtrl properly.

Firstly, I have a directive that generates a form based on a list of properties. So I might have a list of properties for an entity as such:

```
[{
    "name": "name",
    "type": "Text",
    "validation": {
        "minLength": 1,
        "maxLength": 20
    }
},
{
    "name": "role",
    "type": "Entity",
    "entity": "Role",
    "validation": {
        "required": true
    }
}]
```

(if you're familiar with Breeze, this is similar to its [metadata](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/metadata-schema), we're migrating to that soon, having discovered it recently)

A form is generated using a form directive, such as `<foo-form ng-model="user" properties="properties"></foo-form>` where `properties` is the above.

This `fooForm` directive basically iterates through these properties and delegates to another directive called `fooPropertyInput`. Usage is `<foo-property-input ng-model="user.name" property="property"></foo-property-input>`

The responsibility of `fooPropertyInput` is to use the `property` object to display an appropriate input based on the `type` in the property. So if it were text, it should display `<input type="text" ng-model="model"...` or for type Entity, `<foo-entity ng-model="model"...`, etc. The ultimate goal is that this ties into validation properly which reflects in the form defined in `fooForm` (or any other parent form, if used outside of fooForm).

I'm having trouble with understanding how to pass the ngModel and associated properties to the final input elements.

I've done a fair amount of searching for how to use ngModel in this way, but most things come up with using an isolate scope, which I originally understood it's not best practice to use with ngModelCtrl.

Any pointers? Thanks

Edit:
Still looking for an answer, I created a Plunker as requested here with some comments: http://plnkr.co/edit/m8th6GNq4CBoFytmkSN0?p=preview

Also, an additional thought I had, would it be easier to accomplish this if I split up each type into it's own directive (instead of having everything in the template), and require'd the main propertyInput controller? Either way, I think I'm still missing how to link to the HTML input's ngModel (see Plunker comments).

Comment: show us some code, a demo in jsfiddle.net or plunker would also help

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/m8th6GNq4CBoFytmkSN0?p=preview

Here's a basic example, hope that illustrates what I'm trying to understand. Feel free to completely tear it apart as I'm not sure how correct what I've done is. Thanks!